# could someone tell me what wrong with my number to word code?

Tags: php, fatal-error

Here's the class definition I'm using:

```
<?php
class number_word {
    private $word_array = array(1=>"One",2=>"Two",3=>"Three",4=>"Four",5=>"Five",6=>"Six",7=>"Seven",8=>"Eight",9=>"Nine",10=>"Ten",11=>"Eleven",12=>"Twelve",13=>"Thirteen",14=>"Fourteen",15=>"Fifteen",16=>"Sixteen",17=>"Seventeen",18=>"Eighteen",19=>"Nineteen",20=>"Twenty",21=>"Twenty-One",22=>"Twenty-Two",23=>"Twenty-Three",24=>"Twenty-Four",25=>"Twenty-Five",26=>"Twenty-Six",27=>"Twenty-Seven",28=>"Twenty-Eight",29=>"Twenty-Nine",30=>"Thirty",31=>"Thirty-One",32=>"Thirty-Two",33=>"Thirty-Three",34=>"Thirty-Four",35=>"Thirty-Five",36=>"Thirty-Six",37=>"Thirty-Seven",38=>"Thirty-Eight",39=>"Thirty-Nine",40=>"Forty",41=>"Forty-One",42=>"Forty-Two",43=>"Forty-Three",44=>"Forty-Four",45=>"Forty-Five",46=>"Forty-Six",47=>"Forty-Seven",48=>"Forty-Eight",49=>"Forty-Nine",50=>"Fifty",51=>"Fifty-One",52=>"Fifty-Two",53=>"Fifty-Three",54=>"Fifty-Four",55=>"Fifty-Five",56=>"Fifty-Six",57=>"Fifty-Seven",58=>"Fifty-Eight",59=>"Fifty-Nine",60=>"Sixty",61=>"Sixty-One",62=>"Sixty-Two",63=>"Sixty-Three",64=>"Sixty-Four",65=>"Sixty-Five",66=>"Sixty-Six",67=>"Sixty-Seven",68=>"Sixty-Eight",69=>"Sixty-Nine",70=>"Seventy",71=>"Seventy-One",72=>"Seventy-Two",73=>"Seventy-Three",74=>"Seventy-Four",75=>"Seventy-Five",76=>"Seventy-Six",77=>"Seventy-Seven",78=>"Seventy-Eight",79=>"Seventy-Nine",80=>"Eighty",81=>"Eighty-One",82=>"Eighty-Two",83=>"Eighty-Three",84=>"Eighty-Four",85=>"Eighty-Five",86=>"Eighty-Six",87=>"Eighty-Seven",88=>"Eighty-Eight",89=>"Eighty-Nine",90=>"Ninety",91=>"Ninety-One",92=>"Ninety-Two",93=>"Ninety-Three",94=>"Ninety-Four",95=>"Ninety-Five",96=>"Ninety-Six",97=>"Ninety-Seven",98=>"Ninety-Eight",99=>"Ninety-Nine",100=>"One Hundred",200=>"Two Hundred",300=>"Three Hundred",400=>"Four Hundred",500=>"Five Hundred",600=>"Six Hundred",700=>"Seven Hundred",800=>"Eight Hundred",900=>"Nine Hundred");

    private $thousand = array("", "Thousand, ", "Million, ", "Billion, ", "Trillion, ", "Zillion, ");

    private $val, $currency0, $currency1;   
    private $val_array, $dec_value, $dec_word, $num_value, $num_word;
    var $val_word;

    public function number_word($in_val = 0, $in_currency0 = "", $in_currency1 = "") {

        $this->val = $in_val;
        $this->currency0 = $in_currency0;
        $this->currency1 = $in_currency1;

        $this->val = abs(floatval(str_replace(",","",$this->val)));

        if ($this->val > 0) {

            $this->val = number_format($this->val, '2', ',', ',');

            $this->val_array = explode(",", $this->val);

            $this->dec_value = intval($this->val_array[count($this->val_array) - 1]);

            if ($this->dec_value > 0) {

                $this->dec_word = $this->word_array[$this->dec_value]." ".$this->currency1;
            }

            $t = 0;

            for ($i = count($this->val_array) - 2; $i >= 0; $i--) {

                $this->num_value = intval($this->val_array[$i]);

                if ($this->num_value == 0) {
                    $this->num_word = "".$this->num_word;
                } 

                elseif (strlen($this->num_value."") <= 2) {
                    $this->num_word = $this->word_array[$this->num_value]." ".$this->thousand[$t].$this->num_word;
                    // add 'and' if not last element in VAL
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        $this->num_word = " and ".$this->num_word;
                    }               
                } 
                else {
                    $this->num_word = $this->word_array[substr($this->num_value, 0, 1)."00"]. (intval(substr($this->num_value, 1, 2)) > 0 ? " and " : "") .$this->word_array[intval(substr($this->num_value, 1, 2))]." ".$this->thousand[$t].$this->num_word;
                }

            }       
            if (!empty($this->num_word)) {
                $this->num_word .= " ".$this->currency0;
            }
        }
        $this->val_word = $this->num_word." ".$this->dec_word;
    }
}
?>
```

When I try:

```
echo number_word('5,452,455.00','Dollar', 'Cent');
```

I got an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function number_word()
```

Comment: @user485783 ~ Notice I updated your code into your question, using the `{}` button in the editor window. This works for all code blocks. Alternately if you'll prefix the lines with four spaces then they will show in code view automatically (four spaces by hand is fine for one or two lines, otherwise use the button after highlighting the block of code) It is no longer necessary for people to review the code on pastebin `;)`

Answer (score 4):

number_word is a class that contains a function number_word.

you want to do

```
$nw = new number_word();
echo $nw->number_word('5,452,455.00', 'Dollar', 'Cent');
```

or declare the function as static and call

```
echo $nw::number_word('5,452,455.00', 'Dollar', 'Cent');
```

You may want to read the PHP manual about [Classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: the echoing now done, but I'm still having trouble replacing the number format, for example from 5,452,455.28 to 5.452.455,28 if the comma is replaced to a dot only then it can not be read cent, do you have idea? thanks for Your help

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Michael Stum, you'll want to add the below to your number_word() method.

```
return $this->val_word;
```

Comment: but I'm still having trouble replacing the number format, for example from 5,452,455.28 to 5.452.455,28 if the comma is replaced to a dot only then it can not be read cent, what should i do? thanks for Your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at __invoke()

See above link from Mr. Stum.